# Is the iOS Do Not Disturb Bug Causing this Bug?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to find out if the recent Do Not Disturb bug ([Ars Technica link](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/01/ask-ars-why-will-apples-do-not-disturb-bug-fix-itself-next-week/)) is affecting my code. I am trying to get the date and timestamp for midnight the previous Monday. Since I am writing this on a Monday, I would expect to get today's date (January 7, 2013), yet I am January 4, 2013.

I am following the [guide posted by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW12), but I am trying to modify it to find the previous Monday, instead of Sunday.

```
+(NSTimeInterval)StartOfWeekMonday {
    NSTimeInterval finalTime = -1;

    NSInteger weekday;

    NSDate *monday  = 0;

    NSCalendar *greg = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *weekdays = [greg components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *subtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents *final    = 0;

    weekday = ( weekdays.weekday == 1 ) ? 6 : weekdays.weekday;

    [subtract setDay:(0 - weekday - 1)];

    monday = [greg dateByAddingComponents:subtract toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    final  = [greg components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:monday];
    monday = [greg dateFromComponents:final];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog( @"%s - %d -> Weekday: %d", __FILE__, __LINE__, weekday );
    NSLog( @"%s - %d -> Monday: %@", __FILE__, __LINE__, [monday descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]] );
#endif

    finalTime = [monday timeIntervalSince1970];


    return finalTime;
}
```

My log out put below, the weekday is correct (I am writing this on a Monday), yet the date is obviously wrong, it should be `Monday: Monday, January 7, 2013, 12:00 AM`

```
2013-01-07 15:07:33.792 MY-APP[5524:14c03] Weekday: 2
2013-01-07 15:07:36.757 MY-APP[5524:14c03] Monday: Friday, January 4, 2013, 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
```

This is being in the simulator right now, but all my other date calculations are giving the expected values.

Is it likely that I am being affected by the recent Do Not Disturb Bug and will have to wait for tomorrow (January 8, 2013) to see the expected results, or am I missing something entirely different?

Comment: That article is probably not correct about the DND bug; the discrepancy beetween the ISO calendar and Gregorian calendar that the explanation relies on doesn't exist: http://www.tuaw.com/2013/01/03/a-possible-explanation-for-the-ios-new-years-do-not-disturb-bug/ (see Update second paragraph). Have you tried doing your calculations from a dummy date, or moving your system clock around? That should give you some clues.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Heh, these are the consequences of spreading FUD... *"The bug could be related to the ISO week calculation, or it might not; however the working out in this article is definitely flawed in several ways. The blogger responsible has been taken out the back and shot."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with how to calculate the subtraction. Either I completely mis understood the example provided by Apple, or it was not clear enough.  The solution for calculating the subtraction was as follows:

```
weekday = ( weekdays.weekday == 1 ) ? 8 : weekdays.weekday;
toSubtract = ( 2 - weekday );

[subtract setDay:toSubtract];
```

Running various tests produced the proper "Monday." In the end, this had nothing to do with the date bug affecting Do Not Disturb.